# Can an SSIS Lookup Cache be accessed by more than one process at a time-SQL 2008 R2

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to access an SSIS Lookup cache by more than one process at a time?  I have multiple control flow processes that run in parallel.  They all access the same Lookup cache.  One process will stop while the other continues and then restart once that one is done, hence my suspicion that only one process can access the Lookup cache at a time.

Is there a setting or method to change this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered populating a temp table instead of using the Lookup Cache? I had similar issues and found that a temp table performed about as well as a single lookup process but also worked very well for multiple concurrent look ups.